# Test class does not run when I use --runtests

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Test class does not run when I use --runtests

What's up community, I'm trying to deploy a deploy with its respective test class. But the problem is that it does not run the test class and I specify it in the command line.

[image]

This is the command line:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --targetusername areed@user.qa  --manifest releases/package.xml --testlevel RunSpecifiedTests --runtests ClasePruebaAzureTest --checkonly
```

This is the manifest I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
       <members>ClasePruebaAzure</members>
       <members>ClasePruebaAzureTest</members>
       <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your whole command/file is correct as you have shared a screenshot of the validation actually running in org.

Shift you declaration of the `--checkonly` before **testlevel**

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --targetusername areed@user.qa  --manifest releases/package.xml --checkonly --testlevel RunSpecifiedTests --runtests ClasePruebaAzureTest
```

Comment: Try changing the order of the --checkonly and it still doesn't run the test classes. Now I am thinking that it is no longer the command line, but the Org, because, I run the same command line in another Org and it does run the test class.

Comment: Order of switches doesn't matter for sfdx (or most command line commands).